# Javascript range. How insert a HTML Node?

Tags: javascript, jquery, nodes, rich-text-editor

My goal is to replace the text and put it inside the tag . The problem is "Why changing the createTextNode for a 'createHtmlCode'?"

```
        var pannel = $("#text");            
        var $iframe = $("<iframe>").attr("src","iframe.php");
        var iframe = $iframe.get(0);

        pannel.html($iframe);

       //BOLD BUTTON CLICK
        $("#bold").click(function(){                
            iframe.contentWindow.focus();
            iframe.focus();
            iframe.contentDocument.execCommand('bold', false);
            iframe.focus();
        });


        //H1 CLICK, HERE'S THE PROBLEM    
        // Replace the content with tags h1 + actual selection
        $("#h1").click(function(){
            var doc = iframe.contentWindow.document;
            var selected = iframe.contentWindow.getSelection(); 
            console.info(selected);
            if(selected.rangeCount){
                var range = selected.getRangeAt(0);
                var content = range;                    
                var text = new String(selected);
                range.deleteContents();       
                range.insertNode(iframe.contentDocument.createTextNode('<h1>' + text + '<h1>'));                    
            }

        });
```

Comment: 1. Use `$("h1")` instead of `$("#h1")`, # selects tag that contains h1 as its id 2. You should close the h1 tag with `</h1>` here: `createTextNode('<h1>' + text + '<h1>')`

Comment: I put the slash in <h1> text </h1> but continue like text. But i want show a html.